# On JavaScript + asp.net

Tags: asp.net, javascript

In my asp.net page i have java script calendar,on which i want the selected date & then that date has to passed to the code behind's method. How should it be done???

Comment: When do you want to pass it to the server? On postback? On submit?

Answer (score 0):

The JavaScript actually is evaluated at the same time as HTML.
So you can just write the JavaScript with ASP.
You just shouldn't forget to put ' and to escape if you right a string and so on.

Answer (score 0):

If your javascript calendare puts the selected date into a textbox, or into a hidden field, then you should be able to access this on postback.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the value that was selected you need the javascript calendar to write the date into an input box inside a form and that will get sent back as part of the postback.